# encoding of the input (time complexity)

Tags: algorithm, encoding, clrs

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this.
In Cormen page 1056 I read that if the running time of an algorithm is O(k) and "k" is represented in unary i.e. a string of k 1s then running time of the algorithm is 0(n) where "n" is the input-size in bits and if "k" is represented as binary then as n=lg k+1 ,the running time of the algorithm becomes o(2^n).

So my doubt is then why "unary" representation won't be preferred in this case as it gives polynomial time in contrast to exponential in other case.

Comment: I don't understand this.  What is `n`?

Comment: "n" is the length of the input.(bit-size)

Answer (score 6):

Unary time gives polynomial time relative to the input size, but the **actual running time is the same, regardless of the representation used**.

The thing is that complexity is calculated as a function of the input. When using unary representation, you increase the size of the input, while not changing the run time. 

Since to represent `k` in unary base you need `n` bits, `O(k)` is `O(n)` - since it is linear in the size of the input. However, for the same solution, it will be `O(k) = O(2^logk) = O(2^n)`, if you use binary representation since you need `logk` bits to represent `k`.

What you are describing is closely related to [**pseudo-polynomial time**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) algorithms, such as [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) solution with dynamic porogramming which is `O(W*n)`, it is pseudo-polynomial because it is actually **exponential in the number of bits** used to represent `W`.